# UpdatePanel alignment issue inside the Table

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using UpdatePanel control in the middle of the page for partial postback of Address Type radio button change. Everything works fine but I am struggling with alignment issue. The controls inside the UpdatePanel do not align with outside controls. How could I solve this issue? Please let me know.

```
<table id="tblEdit" class="cssclass1" cellpadding="3" runat="server">

    <tr>
        <td class="cssclass1" align="right">
            Title
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" Width="280px" ReadOnly="true"
                BackColor="LightGray" />
        </td>
         <td align="right">
            <asp:Label CssClass="cssclass1" ID="LblFirstName" runat="server">First Name</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="30">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="../../../images/requiredfield.gif" AlternateText="Required Field"
                runat="server"></asp:Image><asp:HiddenField ID="hfCaseEntityId" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>

    <tr>
        <td class="cssclass1" align="right">
            Address Type 
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="AddressType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AddressType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  >
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Home</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Work</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        <td class="cssclass1" align="right">
        </td>
        <td align="left">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label CssClass="cssclass1" ID="LblHomeStreet1" runat="server">Address</asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td align="left">
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtHomeStreet1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" >
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
            <asp:Image ID="Image10" ImageUrl="../../../images/requiredfield.gif" AlternateText="Required Field"
                runat="server"></asp:Image>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label CssClass="cssclass1" ID="LblHomeStreet2" runat="server">Street 2</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
             <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtHomeStreet2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" Width="280px">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label CssClass="cssclass1" ID="LblHomeCity" runat="server">City</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtHomeCity" runat="server" MaxLength="30">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label CssClass="cssclass1" ID="LblHomeState" runat="server">State</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtHomeState" runat="server" MaxLength="30">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid.  The first line in your `<ContentTemplate>` is a `<tr>`, however, it looks like you are trying to include another `<table>` there.  You might want to look into cellpading=0 and cellspacing=0 on your inner table.  Also, you could add a CSSClass to your UpdatePanel to do any additional formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. <tr> is not an extra tag. Could you please give me more details?

Comment: Sorry, table should have been in the above statment.  You should be putting another table element prior to that tr tag.  You basically have an orphaned row.